# How to increase height of bar in ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2

In the following plot:

[image]

I would like to increase the height of those tiny bars (such as the bars of 5%, 3%, etc.) so that the percent becomes more clear.

The script I have written:

```
ggplot(xx, aes(x = Group, y = Freq, group = Count)) +
    geom_col(aes(fill = Count), position = 'fill',color = "black") +
    geom_text(aes(label = percent(z, accuracy = 1)), position = position_fill(vjust = .5)) +
    theme_bw() +
    theme(text = element_text(face = "bold", size = 20), legend.position = "bottom", legend.title = element_blank()) + ylab("Frequency ") + labs(fill='Method type') +
    #scale_x_discrete(labels=c("a" = "1", "b" = "2", "c" = "3")) +
    guides(fill=guide_legend(nrow=2,byrow=TRUE)) +
    scale_fill_brewer(type = "seq", palette = "Greys")
```

Do you know how to do that?

Comment: You don't need to increase the height of the bars, you just need to either: a) save the image with larger dimensions (e.g. `ggsave('myplot.png), height  = 8, width = 12, units = 'cm'`), or b) play around with the plot to make things fit, e.g. make the font size smaller, move the legend to the right or left size, etc...

Comment: Another option would be to add `geom_label(fill = 'white')` instead of `geom_text()`

Comment: Can you provide a sample of your data so we can help you better?

Comment: @AdamB is right. The plot appearance hugely depends on the size of your device and eventually on the size of file output. It makes sense to first decide how big your image / figure should be, and define your plot dimensions accordingly (font size, line thickness, margins, etc... )